# Swift 3 simulate keyboard button return clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is it possible to simualate the return button on iphone keyboard?

I have a webview where i parse a value, and when this is done, i like to simulate a return pressed, instead of the user maually clicking return.

From my View2 i call View 1 and parse a value to my webview textfield, then i want to call the return button on the keyboard without doing it in real time.

is this possible?

Comment: `resigneFirstResponder` will help you..

Comment: @Dhiru, is it still possible after i updated my question?

Comment: VIew1 and View2 are `UIView` ? and are they are within same  `superView`

Comment: They are UIViewControllers and have two different views. View2 is a barCode scanning controller and View1 is my ViewController.

Comment: did u try `self.view.endEditing=true;`  where you want to dismiss the `keyboard` ?

Comment: Yes i have, but maybe my problem is the focus is not on the webview textfield?

Comment: @Dhiru, is it possible to discuss it over the chat?

Comment: send a tagged msg on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144892/ios-dev-expert  @rijoh